# Mex compilation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compilation, mex

I have matlab 2012b and I am trying to run mex -setup but it is complaining about not finding compilers. My question is does matlab 2012b only support up to the compilers of 2010 visual studio? I own visual studio 2013 but do I need to install windows sdk 7.1 (I have a windows 7 64-bit machine)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supported compilers for R2012b on Windows 64-bit are listed at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2012b/win64.html.

To answer your question, you need either Visual Studio 2010 (professional), Visual Studio 2008 (Pro, SP1) + Windows SDK 6.1, or Windows SDK 7.1.

Comment: If I install windows SDK 7.1 will I have to worry about my compilers for visual studio 2013 not working properly?

Comment: I don't know, this is more related to Visual Studio than MATLAB, probably best to ask on the appropriate forum.